# Accessing a linux file content through an url

Tags: linux, python, http

I want to access a Linux file content through an url. When we access the url we can see the content of that file being displayed in the screen. Is there any procedure to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file with path `/x/y/z`, `curl` can use the `file://` protocol to do that:

```
curl file:///x/y/z
```

Example:

```
$ curl file:///etc/hosts   
#
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#

#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost
```